# Invalid fields for site for Yodlee

Tags: java, php, asp.net, http-post, yodlee

I am new to yodlee trying to test the app, I am making a post call with

url -->>https://developer.api.yodlee.com:443/ysl/restserver/v1/providerAccounts?providerId=10588 
 where 10588 is the provider id for yes bank and sending the data as

```
 {
"field": [
 {
  "id": "77398",
  "value": "user id"
 },
 {
  "id": "77399",
  "value": "password"
 }
 ]}
```

In response I am getting

```
{    "errorCode": "Y400",
     "errorMessage": "Invalid fields for site ...",                  
     "referenceCode": "S1505215393036o4j27f"
}
```

I believe the user id and password id provided are wrong but yodlee is giving the same id for yes bank, If any one can help regarding the same??

Answer (score 0):

The field Ids doesn't seem to be right. Can you try with the following login form for YES BANK (edit the **value** field?

Hope this helps.

```
{
  "loginForm": {
    "row": [{
      "field": [{
        "id": 29421,
        "value": "username"
       }]
     },
     {
      "field": [{
        "id": 29420,
        "value": "password"
       }]
     }]
  }
}
```